# Using plotyy with multiple data sets with different dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, runtime-error, dimensions

I want to produce a plot with two y-axis and apply multiple datasets to one of the axis. For example

```
[hAx,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy([x1',x2',x3'],[y1',y2',y3'],x4,y4);
```

where `x1` and `y1` are `1000x1`-arrays, `x2` and `y2` are `2000x1`-arrays and `x3` and `y3` are `3000x1`-arrays. The range of the arrays is more or less the same. When i try producing this plot, MATLAB gets me an error saying

> Error using horzcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not
>   consistent.

Is there any workaround for this error?

EDIT:
Here's my real code, which is not working:

```
[hAx,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy([erg_cm.Time.data,erg_cm.Time.data,t',t'],...
    [erg_cm.Car_FxFL.data,erg_cm.Car_FxFR.data,Fx(1,:),Fx(2,:)],...
    erg_cm.Time.data,diff);
```

And my original data:

- `erg_cm.Time.data` is `1x4001`
- `t` is `80300x1`
- `erg_cm.Car_FxFL.data` is `1x4001`
- `erg_cm.Car_FxFR.data` is `1x4001`
- `Fx` is `4x80300`
- `diff` is `1x4001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x` and `y` vectors are column vectors and you're trying to concatenate them horizontally, which you cannot do because they are not the same size. You want to vertically concatenate them:

```
[hAx,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy([x1;x2;x3],[y1;y2;y3],x4,y4);
```

EDIT: This is what I'm testing with

```
erg_cm.Time.data = rand(1, 4001);
t =  rand(80300, 1);
erg_cm.Car_FxFL.data = rand(1, 4001);
erg_cm.Car_FxFR.data = rand(1, 4001);
Fx = rand(4, 80300);
diff = rand(1, 4001);

[hAx,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy([erg_cm.Time.data,erg_cm.Time.data,t',t'],...
    [erg_cm.Car_FxFL.data,erg_cm.Car_FxFR.data,Fx(1,:),Fx(2,:)],...
    erg_cm.Time.data,diff);
```

Comment: oh wow.... tbh in my case they originally were row vectors, and i transponed them, because - for some stupid reason - i thought, they ought to be column vectors. Well, this works, thank you very much again, excaza!

Comment: ok, i thought it would have solved the problem, because after i tried it, i got another error instead of this one. but when i solved the other error, this one reappeared, so my original question remains. i will edit it though

Comment: @Max then one of your arrays isn't the correct shape. I've updated with the test case I'm using, which functions correctly. Can you please update your OP with the output of `whos`? It would help to see the shape of all of your data.

Comment: sorry i didn't make it yesterday! i now updated my OP and added the actual code i'm trying to get to work with the data structure. But what is `whos`?

Comment: ok, I read the documentation about `whos`... I think that would be too confusing since the data I'm using comes from huge structs of simulation results. I hope the information i provided is enough for you to help me. Otherwise i can of course post the output of `whos` as well.

Comment: @Max I have updated my test case, which functions as expected.

Comment: really? Well, I just don't see why it's not working for me than. I give up and switch to the `line`-command option, you suggested in the other thread... Thank you very much for your help and the time, that you invested!